# Generate matrix symmetric and positive-definite

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

I want to apply Conjugated Gradient Method to a **random matrix** of size nxn. This method needs that the matrix **symmetric** and **positive definite**. I am doing this in Matlab and C++.

I know how to do a simetric matrix but I don't know how I could make a matrix positive definite.

I was reading in this post that I can generate it doing A=A'*A and I don't care of values range.
[How to make a matrix positive definite whose elements lie in the range 0.8 to 1 and -0.8 to -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404881/how-to-make-a-matrix-positive-definite-whose-elements-lie-in-the-range-0-8-to-1#comment35861619_23405180)

It is true? If not, how can I generate it?

Comment: Have.... you... tried it?

Comment: I was reading how to comprobate, but I don't know if I can generate directly a random matrix

Comment: You can find the answer to all that with very quick google searches

Comment: A matrix is positive-(semi)definite if all the eigenvalues are positive (non-negative).  If you square a matrix, it will square all the eigenvalues.  If they were real, squaring them makes them non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result returned by Google when I searched for a method to create symmetric positive definite matrices in Matlab points to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab). Let's take the function posted in the accepted answer (its syntax actually needs to be fixed a little bit):

```
function A = generateSPDmatrix(n)
    A = rand(n);
    A = 0.5 * (A + A');
    A = A + (n * eye(n));
end
```

Now, checking if a given matrix is symmetric is very easy in Matlab, all you have to do is to use the built-in [issymmetric function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/issymmetric.html). As stated in this thread, the [chol function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html) can be helpful to determine whether a matrix is positive definite or not... but it may fail in some situations and it's overall very costly on a computational point of view. Fortunately, another approach can be used if the matrix is symmetric: checking if all its eigenvalues are positive. Let's put all this together:

```
function res = is_SPD(M)
    if (~issymmetric(M))
        res = false;
        return;
    end

    ev = eig(M);

    if (any(ev <= 0))
        res = false;
        return;
    end

    res = true;
end
```

And, finally, let's run a few tests:

```
res = zeros(1,10);

for i = 1:10
    M = generateSPDmatrix(20);
    res(i) = is_SPD(M);
end

disp(res);
```

Comment: The comprobation works well I tested it with a matrix [4 1; 1 3] that I know it is positive definite and simetrical and the result is one. But these 2 methods don't create matrix with these characteristics. All the results are 0

Comment: This method does a simmetrical and positive definite. A = A*A' because the result is 1

Comment: A = 0.5*(A+A');  is the same as   A = A*A';

Comment: I tested the program with A=0.5(A+A')  and this is the result 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0. The same result with A = A + n*eye(n). Furthermore I displayed the matrix M and I can see that is not simetrical.

Comment: A = A + n*eye(n) it can create a positive definite but no simetrical

Comment: Man, relax and read carefully. The generateSPDmatrix function creates an SPD matrix, not any single random line of code inside it. If you want an SPD matrix, call generateSPDmatrix to get one.

Comment: Ok, it works but before that you edited there was a OR